# Would I use reactnative as a child view in a native ui view?

Tags: android, uiview, react-native, childviews

i just want to use ReactNative as a child view in the native layout, can i do that?

ex: as an android app, layout A's content view is a native LinerLayout , and there is two child views in layout A, one is a native header view, and the other , i want to use the ReactNative..

Is this ok? And how ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally...i just find the answer is ok...and it is easy to do that...